# How is &> redirection implemented in UNIX shells?

Tags: c, io-redirection

We know that `&> outfile` redirects both `stdout` and `stderr` to `outfile` in a UNIX shell. But how does the shell implement this? I write a naïve test:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main()
{
    int fd = open("tmpf", O_CREAT | O_TRUNC | O_WRONLY, 0644);
    // redirect stdout to file
    dup2(fd, 1);
    close(fd);
    // redirect stderr to stdout
    dup2(2, 1);
    close(2);
    // print stuff to file
    fprintf(stdout, "stdout string\n");
    fprintf(stderr, "stderr string\n");
}
```

It simply redirects `stdout` to the file and then redirects `stderr` to `stdout`. But this doesn't work. The above code produces

```bash
$ ./a.out
stdout string
$ cat tmpf
$
```

If we exchange the order of `stdout->file` and `stderr->stdout`, it gives the following result

```bash
$ ./a.out
$ cat tmpf
stdout string
$
```

Comment: This isn't a `sh` feature at all -- it's a `bash` extension. Baseline `sh` shells do not support it. (`csh` does, and is where the inspiration came from, but that's not POSIX-family at all).

Comment: Fd 2 is stderr. You're closing it and then trying to write to it...

Comment: And it's _exactly_ like `>file 2>&1` -- opening FD 1 to your destination, and then using `dup2()` to make FD 2 be a duplicate of FD 1. Why do you have a `close()` in the process at all? Consider using `strace` to watch what a real shell does during the operation at hand.

Comment: Removed the `sh` and `bash` tags, as the knowledge needed to solve the problem has nothing to do with understanding the shell command language.

Comment: ...re: `&>` in shell, see https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't close your destination FDs. The only FD you should close is the handle on `tmpf`; both stdout and stderr need to be open to be able to write to them.

Also, it should be `dup2(1,2)` to copy stdout to stderr -- coping stderr to stdout (as the original code does) discards your handle on `tmpf`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main()
{
    int fd = open("tmpf", O_CREAT | O_TRUNC | O_WRONLY, 0644);
    // copy FD to stdout ("redirect stdout to fd")
    dup2(fd, 1);
    // fd was copied to stdout so we don't need the original
    close(fd);
    // copy stdout fd to stderr ("redirect stdout to stderr")
    dup2(1, 2);
    // print stuff to file
    fprintf(stdout, "stdout string\n");
    fprintf(stderr, "stderr string\n");
}
```

Also see this running in an online sandbox at https://replit.com/@CharlesDuffy2/KnowingWobblyFibonacci#main.c (you can use "Show files" to see the resulting `tmpf` file in output).

Comment: Last night I was terribly exhausted and I made a mistake: redirecting `stderr` to `stdout` should be `dup2(1, 2)`, analogous to redirecting `stdout` to file: `dup2(outfile, 1)`. But it's not completely analogous to it, as you pointed out only opened file should be closed (`close(1)` shouldn't happen). And I just [fixed my shell's problem](https://github.com/How-u-doing/msh/commit/37b71f36a316091ada163b5d1e105e688755c231).